# Highly available windows service

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, windows-services

I am developing a Windows Service (.NET, C#). One of the non functional requirement is to ensure the high availability of this Windows Service. I understand that installing this Windows Service on a Failover Cluster will make this highly available. To install this service on a Cluster, is there any specific code I have to write within this service? I have heard about cluster aware services, however I have not came across any article that explains how to develop a cluster aware windows service. Is it really required to make a windows service to install it on a cluster?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Failover Cluster Services allows for this high availability without the need for you to code complicated heartbeats into your service. The Failover Cluster Service manages this for you.

For more information on [Failover Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/failover-clustering-overview)

For Windows Services, there generally isn't much you need to do beyond [writing your windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-create-windows-services). That said, you may need to use the [Failover Cluster API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296100(v=vs.85).aspx) in your code if you need to know about your environment from your code, use local resources such IP addresses/disks, etc. However, most simple services I've seen don't require modifications to make calls to the Clustering APIs and can be installed directly into a properly configured failover cluster with the proper resource groups defined.

View Microsoft's guidance on [writing Cluster Aware applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369082(v=vs.85).aspx).

Visit [Creating a failover cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/create-failover-cluster) for help and for services, the clustered role type should be "Generic Service".

Cheers,
cbuzzsaw

Answer (score 1):

First of all this question is EXTREMELY broad, but here are my two cents.

It depends on the service.

If executing multiple instances simultaneously of your service doesn't breaks it's purpose, then you don't need to do nothing, if there can be only one service being executed then you must coordinate these instances (udp broadcast messages maybe?) to only have one active and in the case the instance which is active stops start another one.

A cluster is just a bunch of machines  with a same purpose (yes yes, there is a lot more of things but for this case that comparison is enough), so think it as if you were running that service on a local network in multiple machines.

Comment: There will be only one instance of the service running at any point in time. If one fails, another one should automatically start running. How can this be implemented?

Comment: As I described, all the services must be running but only one is active, the others would be waiting for the case of a failure, then you must create a mechanism to coordinate all the running services, per example the active service must broadcast each X seconds a packet to the network, if the inactive services don't receive that broadcast for X seconds then the next service will become active and the same technique applies again, broadcast, wait, no packet? new service active.